# How to process webpage remotely and access it locally

Tags: 18.04

So a webpage that I'm visiting is rather cpu intensive.. I want to be able to process it remotely and access it locally. I tried X forwarding which was ridiculously slow as well as ssh -L, which didn't seem to work. Is there anyway to do this or am I barking at the wrong tree?

Comment: Maybe not the wrong tree, but your case is not very clear. You have to give more specific details.

Comment: So the website is an old MMO game, which takes a lot of cpu processing and is extremely power intensive. I want a solution that can help me access the webpage without actually forcing my computer to process. I tried ssh -X but the result was extreme lag. I also tried ssh -L a specific port, but it cannot connect properly. From what I know, a SOCKS proxy will still force my local computer to process the data.

Comment: Please, expand you original question with this information and somebody may help you. Personally, I do not think port forwarding will be of any help here (but, I may be wrong).